# Word wrap problem in MFC when using UTF-8 codepage

Tags: mfc, word-wrap

My MFC application supports 14 languages. The code page is being set to UTF-8 in the manifest for the application. Some controls are set to be multiline controls (static text, check boxes) and wrapping works just fine in English. But in some languages, the line breaks are being done on special characters instead of the space character. The controls look just fine in the resource editor, but at run-time they are messed up.

The example here shows a Spanish string in the resource editor (left image) that is being wrapped correctly, but not correctly at run-time (right image).

Any ideas what is happening or how to fix this?

[image: Resource editor image]
[image: Run-time image]

Edit: This problem started happening when the UTF-8 code page was added to the manifest

Comment: This looks like a Windows bug to be. Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page if you have not already done do.

Comment: What type of control is this, and which version of the Common Controls is this using? Is the control dynamically created or described in an .rc file? In the latter case, what character encoding is the .rc file saved as?

Comment: @Jabberwocky That URL is where we got the information about adding UTF-8 to our manifest.

Comment: @IInspectable The problem happens with static text and check boxes (that we've noticed so far. There may be other controls with the same issue). I'm not exactly sure which version of Common Controls this is using. We're using Visual Studio 19, but I have CC 5.82 and 6.1 on my system. These controls are all contained in .rc files. The .rc files appear to be ANSI-encoded (according to Notepad++). We aren't specifically setting the encoding, so whatever VS is doing...

Comment: So why do you set the UTF-8 codepage in the manifest in the first place?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Our customers have a need to run our app in various languages on an English OS. Adding the UTF-8 codepage in the manifest allows for displaying of all the non-English strings without the user having to switch to a different code page in the OS. It works great, except for this word wrap problem.